# Consulta através de dblink está dando erro ORA-02022

Tags: postgresql, pl-sql

Boa noite, estou fazendo uma consulta pelo PL/SQL em um banco de dados postgres, conectado por um dblink, no postgres a view é executada corretamente, porém quando consulto através do dbllink fica dando o erro  ORA-02022. Alguém sabe o que devo fazer para corrigir isso?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A doc diz "Remote statement has unoptimized view with remote object" passou a sql em analise no PostgreSQL ? Mas da forma que a pergunta só vidente para saber responder.

Comment: No caso eu criei uma view no postgres e estou tentando consultar ela no pl/sql através do dblink e está dando esse erro, no pgadmin rodou normal.

Comment: A pergunta é relevante e pode ajudar a comunidade em casos semelhantes.